# cannot send email to multiple recepients using phpmailer

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

I'm trying to send an email to multiple recipients using phpmailer and getting the emails list from my table in the database, however, whenever I make a request only one recipient, the first one on the list gets the email. *I know this might be marked as duplicate but I couldn't find a similar example using mysql

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($errors)) {

    $thisType = mysql_prep($_POST["partner_type"]);
    $content = $_POST["content"];
    $header = $_POST["header"];
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM partners_list WHERE partner_type = '$thisType' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

        require_once("phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
        require_once("phpMailer/class.smtp.php");
        require_once("phpMailer/language/phpmailer.lang-uk.php");

        $to_name = "Order";
        $subject = $header;
        $message = $content;
        $message = wordwrap($message,70);
        $from_name = "thisCompany";
        $from = "noreply@thicCompany.com";

        $mail = new PHPMailer();

            $mail->AddAddress($row['email'], "Test Message"); // add each DB entry to list of recipients

        $mail->FromName = $from_name;
        $mail->From     = $from;
        $mail->Subject  = $subject;
        $mail->Body     = $message;

        $result = $mail->Send();

        // Success
        $_SESSION["message"] = "e-mail successfully sent.";
        redirect_to("successpage.php");
        }
}
 } else {
} 
?>
```

Comment: only loop the code you need to, currently you call `require_once("phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php");` etc for every email

Comment: @Dagon it works fine now.. Thanks. modified to `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $mail->AddAddress($row['email'], "Test Message"); // add each DB entry to list of recipients
        }`

Comment: wasn't exactly expecting it to solve the problem just be a real good idea - all good.

Comment: I'd recommend you use [the mailing list example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) that's provided with PHPMailer. It's much more efficient than what you've got, and not based on obsolete code.